# How to print One random character from email id where special characters like @ and . are excluded?

Tags: python, random

I tried using random library in python for printing one random character from email id but I don't want any special characters to be printed. How will I do that?

```
import random
Email_id = 'rajat123@gmail.com' 
f = random.choice(Email_id [0])
print(f)
```

Comment: You're making a random choice from the first character of the address (`Email_id[0]`), so this will always be `'r'`. If you don't want a random choice from `Email_id`, but you want a random choice from all the non-special characters from `Email_id`, what is the first thing you should do? (StackOverflow is a great place for help, but most users have little patience for laziness)

Comment: I can use f = random.choice(Email_id)  which will print any random character from mail id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import re
Email_id = 'rajat123@gmail.com'
f = random.choice(re.sub(r'\W+', '', Email_id))
print(f)
```

`re.sub` will skip all special characters except numbers, letters and _

Comment: If we have a list like -- User_details = ['rajat', 'rajat1996maan@gmail.com', '8700085479'] and we want to print one character from email id, how will I do that?

Comment: `User_details = ['rajat', 'rajat1996maan@gmail.com', '8700085479']`

`f = random.choice(re.sub(r'\W+', '', User_details[1]))`

Comment: Do you mean you have a list like `User_details = ['rajat', 'rajat1996maan@gmail.com', '8700085479']`

Comment: I also tried the same thing by putting the index in user_details

Comment: while appending f in an empty list, it showing None in the list.

Comment: Ok, so you have a list like this `User_details = ['rajat', 'rajat1996maan@gmail.com', '8700085479']`. And you want to print a random char from the emailId right? Is that the only goal here?

Comment: Its done. The main goal is to create a passkey of 16 digits by taking random characters of 4 list and append them in the list. The main problem that came across is what you solved. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is my question is unclear or not useful? Someone give me -1 rating for that

Comment: Your problem is an easy one. You might have put some more effort to get it done . by yourself or People might have asked similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random
Email_id = 'rajat123@gmail.com' 
filtered = [c for c in Email_id if c.isalnum()]
f = random.choice(filtered)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

use, replace() method to remove '@' and '.', other methods ( re.sub() and isalnum() ) will replace all special characters from Email_id.

```
import random
Email_id = 'rajat123@gmail.com' 
f = random.choice(Email_id.replace("@", "").replace(".",""))
print(f)
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.